What is the asymptotic distribution of $Y_n/X_n$?
This question comes to mind out of curiosity (I may be wrong).
Let there be two sequences of random variables $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$. Now
$$
a_N (X_n - \mathbb{E}(X_n)) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,\sigma_1^2)\quad\text{and}\quad b_N (Y_n - \mathbb{E}(Y_n)) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,\sigma_2^2).
$$
We also know that $a_N < b_N\ \forall N$  (for example $n^2 < n^3 \quad \forall n>1$). Then what is the asymptotic distribution of $Y_n/X_n$?
Does the Delta method serve any purpose here? or any other method is required for this type of asymptotic?
Any suggestions or literatures about this kind of thing is helpful for me.

Suppose that $\frac{a_n}{a_n+b_n}\rightarrow\lambda$ with $1<\lambda<1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then $\frac{b_n}{a_n+b_n}\rightarrow 1 -\lambda$. Furthermore, suppose that $$\begin{pmatrix} a_n(X_n - \mu_X) \\ b_n(Y_n - \mu_Y) \end{pmatrix}\rightarrow Z$$ in distribution as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where $Z$ is an $\mathbb R^2$-valued random variable with distribution $$\mathcal N\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_X^2 & \rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho \\ \rho\sigma_Y\sigma_X & \sigma_Y^2 \end{pmatrix}\right).$$ Then $$\frac{a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}\begin{pmatrix} X_n - \mu_X \\ Y_n - \mu_Y \end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1 - \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix}Z,$$ and applying the Delta Method yields $$\frac{a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}\big(f(X_n,Y_n) - f(\mu_X,\mu_Y)\big)\rightarrow f'(\mu_X,\mu_Y)^\top\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix} Z$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where the function $f$ is given by $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$ with derivative $$f'(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{y} \\ -\frac{x}{y^2} \end{pmatrix}.$$ That is, the asymptotic variance of $$\frac{a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}\big(f(X_n,Y_n) - f(\mu_X,\mu_Y)\big)$$ is given by $$V := (1-\lambda)\frac{1}{\mu_Y^2}\sigma_X^2 - \frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y^3}\rho\sigma_X\sigma_X +\lambda \frac{\mu_X^2}{\mu_Y^4}\sigma_Y^2.$$ If the sequences $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are independent, then $\rho = 0$ and the middle term vanishes.

I think that that knowing $a_n<b_n$ for all $n>1$ is not enough. Intuitively, you want to combine the asymptotic behavior of two sequences. But to do so, you need to know how fast $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ grow relatively to each other. My assumption corresponds to a proportional growth (where $\lambda$ is the factor of proportionality). Other assumptions work, too. Without any assumption on the growth rates, I am pretty sure that you could end up in a situation where one growth rate is very large, while the other one is very small. Then you only reach the asymptotic behavior of the former, while the latter may already degenerated to zero or infinity. However, note that this is just an heuristic consideration.
